# UITableViewCell redrawing on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that contains cells with a slider and two labels, each time a slider goes out of view it appears to be drawn again on top of the current content.

Here is a gif explaining what I mean.

http://i.imgur.com/4dYtyJy.gifv

And here is the relevant code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let CellIdentifier: String = "\(indexPath.row) - \(indexPath.section)"
    var cell: UITableViewCell! = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier)

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }

    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 16.0, width: 300, height: 30.0))
    let percentageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 0, width: 200.0, height: 30.0))
    let slider = CustomUISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 55.0, width: 300.0, height: 20.0))

    slider.maximumTrackTintColor = Global().turqTint
    slider.minimumTrackTintColor = Global().blueTint
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0
    slider.value = 0.0
    slider.tag = indexPath.row
    slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "sliderThumbImage"), forState: .Normal)
    slider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    label.text = Array(selectedTypes)[indexPath.row].1

    percentageLabel.text = "\(slider.value)"
    percentageLabel.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.tintColor = Global().tintColor
    cell.addSubview(label)
    cell.addSubview(slider)
    cell.addSubview(percentageLabel)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: iOS would call cellForRowAtIndexPath when it is going to appear. Since you add subviews to it every time, it would add a new sliding view while scrolling. Try to move them inside the if cell == nil block

Comment: Thank you @Horst - would you like to submit this as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. As Horst said in the comments, putting that snippet inside the block will do the trick:

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    // Code that draws frames
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist to go with your way, you would like to have something more like
(**Note**: `"\(indexPath.row) - \(indexPath.section)"`) this will create different CellIDs for every cell. What you would like to have is some common CellID to be able to benefit from the reuse logic of the TableView:

```
//Global constants for the View tags
let textLabelTag = 1
let percentageLabelTag = 2
let sliderTag = 3

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let CellIdentifier: String = "SomeUniqueID"
    var cell: UITableViewCell! = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier)

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
        self.createUIforCell(cell);
    }

    self.configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

    return cell
}
```

1. Create the UI components for the cell and add them as subviews. This method will be called only once if the cell doesn't exist:

   ```
   func createUIforCell(cell: UITableViewCell) {

      let textLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 16.0, width: 300, height: 30.0))
      textLabel.tag = textLabelTag
      cell.addSubview(textLabel)

      let percentageLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 0, width: 200.0, height: 30.0))
      percentageLabel.tag = percentageLabelTag
      cell.addSubview(percentageLabel)

      let slider = CustomUISlider(frame: CGRect(x: 16.0, y: 55.0, width: 300.0, height: 20.0))
      slider.tag = sliderTag
      slider.maximumTrackTintColor = Global().turqTint
      slider.minimumTrackTintColor = Global().blueTint
      slider.minimumValue = 0.0
      slider.maximumValue = 1.0
      slider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "sliderThumbImage"), forState: .Normal)
      slider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueChanged:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
      cell.addSubview(slider)
   }
   ```
2. Update the UI with the correct data:

   ```
   func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

       let textLabel: UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(textLabelTag) as! UILabel
       textLabel.text = Array(selectedTypes)[indexPath.row].1

       let slider: CustomUISlider = cell.viewWithTag(sliderTag) as! CustomUISlider
       slider.value = 0.0

       let percentageLabel: UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(percentageLabelTag) as! UILabel
       percentageLabel.text = "\(slider.value)"

   }
   ```

**Note**: It'll be cleaner if you've your own UITableViewCell subclass where the UI to be created (either in the code or in .xib)

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass `UITableViewCell` and override `prepeareForReuse` method. With it you can set your cell to default mode.

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];

    //Reset your cell here to default state.
}
```